# Bootstrap form dropdown validation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on this bootstrap dropdown and the form still submits even though nothing has been selected. The inputs work. When left blank the form doesnt submit, but doesn't work in the dropdown selects. Any ideas? I've tried required, required="true", and required="required" on the select element.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

```
<div class="form-group--custom form-group">
   <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-link" id="C_Salutation" name="C_Salutation" title="Title" value="">
   <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;" id="C_Country-Placeholder">Business Markets Served*</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see `required` in your code?

What about using required this way...

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" required>
     <option value disabled selected>Business Markets Served*</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```